# reinterpret_cast of __uint128_t

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

As I know reinterpret_cast must not lead to data loss.

So it is not possible to compile such code in X86_64 due integer is smaller than pointer

```
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
    int a = 123;
    int res = reinterpret_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(a));
    printf("%d", a == res);
}
```

The question is: why I can compile such code in GCC and Clang?

```
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
    __uint128_t a = 4000000000000000000;
    a *= 100;
    __uint128_t res = reinterpret_cast<__uint128_t>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(a));
    printf("%d", a == res);
}
```

And the result I get is "0", means that there is a data loss.

**Edit**

I think there are 3 possible variants what it could be.
Compiler bug, abuse of spec, or consequence of spec.
Which one is this?

Comment: Learn early and well that _undefined behaviour_ exists, and just being able to compile/run something does **not** mean that it's valid or safe C++ code. `reinterpret_cast` just tells the compiler 'I think I know what I am doing, so let me do it', but it is clearly documented which casts are actually valid, and the compiler won't stop you from doing ones that aren't valid.

Comment: @underscore_d I think `reinterpret_cast` definitely protects you in some cases. I am interested why it is not doing it now.

Comment: you just have 8 higher bytes or so. it's like `mov ax , WORD PTR some_dword`  in masm

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP `reinterpret_cast must not lead to data loss` Think you misread that, and the above is not the only case where this can happen.

Comment: @dxiv Can you show some other cases with reinterpret_cast? I didn't find much.

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP Maybe not "*data loss*" per se, but the standard [notes](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast) that "*the mapping performed by `reinterpret_­cast` might, or might not, produce a representation different from the original value*". One example from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) is that '*the same pointer may have multiple integer representations*", which is in fact fairly common in segment-offset architectures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's explained here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

> 2. A pointer can be converted to any integral type large enough to hold all values of its type (e.g. to std::uintptr_t)

That's why you have an error for the first case

> 3. A value of any integral or enumeration type can be converted to a pointer type...

that's why you don't have an error, but it wraps to 0 in the second case. it somehow assumes that pointer type has the biggest range compared to any integral types, whereas with 128 bits integers it's not the case.

Note that a 128 bit integer is not an integral type generally speaking but at least gcc defines it as is in gcc extensions:

from https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/02/28/is-int128-integral/

> libstdc++ (in standard, non-gnu++XX mode) leaves is_integral_v<__int128> as false. This makes a certain amount of sense from the library implementor’s point of view, because __int128 is not one of the standard integral types, and furthermore, if you call it integral, then you have to face the consequence that intmax_t (which is 64 bits on every ABI that matters) is kind of lying about being the “max.”

but

> In -std=gnu++XX mode, libstdc++ makes is_integral_v<__int128> come out to true

Comment: But void* can't hold the value of __uint128_t. I don't have original value as you see in second example. If the value was original, printf would give "1".

Comment: I edited to clarify. It looks that the reinterpret cast isn't safe in that case.

Comment: Actually this part looks like a solution:
(the round-trip conversion in the opposite direction is not guaranteed; the same pointer may have multiple integer representations)
Which is a little bit confusing, I think it is a correct opinion that compiler devs assume that pointer type is the biggest.

Comment: Mostly I don't get if it is a bug of compiler, abuse of spec, or consequence of spec.

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP Spec says any integer can be converted to a pointer, so it's a consequence of the spec.

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP It's pretty much never a compiler bug, that's a reasonable assumption to have with language features that are decades old. Brand new C++ features do suffer from compiler and library bugs, and even from bugs (ahem, deficiencies) in the standard. But those casts, as you use them, are old news.

Comment: Your second quote is inapplicable. __uint128_t is not an "integral type".

Comment: no, not in general, but in gcc extension it is, see my edit (good point at any rate)